# How to lazify output in Tabbed Layout in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to create a tabbed layout in jupyter notebook using `ipywidgets`. I want to process the output of a particular tab only when it is clicked. In other words, lazify the output.

```py
from ipywidgets import widgets

out1 = widgets.Output()
with out1:
    get_output_1()

out2 = widgets.Output()
with out2:
    get_output_2()

out = widgets.Tab([out1, out2])
out.set_title(0, 'out1')
out.set_title(1, 'out2')

display(out)
```

I want the functions `get_output_1()` and `get_output_2()` to be called only when the corresponding tab is clicked.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `observe` function to detect which tab is being selected, and then choose the correct Output widget from a dictionary, run your function and then display the return value.

You might want your long running function to have the `@lru_cache` decorator so that as you flick backwards and forward between tabs you have a shorter wait time.

```py
    from IPython.display import clear_output, display
    import time
    import ipywidgets as widgets
    from functools import lru_cache

    # set up a dictionary of Output widgets
    outputs = {i: widgets.Output() for i in range(0,3)}

    # add the Output widgets as tab childen
    tab = widgets.Tab()
    tab.children = list(outputs.values())
    for i, title in outputs.items():
        tab.set_title(i, 'Tab '+str(i))

    def print_on_select(widget):
    #     get the correct Output widget based on the index of the chosen tab
        tab_idx = widget['new']
        output_widget = outputs[tab_idx]
        with output_widget:
            clear_output()
            print('running long function')
            value = long_running_function(tab_idx)
            clear_output()
            print(value)

    @lru_cache(32)
    def long_running_function(tab_idx):
        time.sleep(2)
        return 'this is tab number ' + str(tab_idx)

    tab.observe(print_on_select, names='selected_index')

    display(tab)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! One thing which might be worth adding is the code for showing the contents of the initial tab without any interaction using `with outputs[0]: display('something')`  just before the call to the `observe()`.