# Output widget appears outside tab widget when using nbconvert on jupyter notebook with ipywidgets

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, nbconvert

I created a notebook which should display plots in a tab widget. As far as I understand, to include something like plots in the tab widget, I need to wrap it in the output widget. In the notebook itself it works but when I convert it to html via nbconvert it produces the wrong output.

Widgets like sliders, buttons or text appear within the tab widget where they should, but when I use the output widget to catch the plot (or even some text from a print() function) it appears before the tab environment which itself is then empty.

This is the how it shoud look with one plot per tab (works in the notebook):
[Plots in tabs within notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2B3m.png)

And this is how it looks after nbconvert (in html). The plots appear before the tab envorinment:
[Plots before tabs in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CiYw.pngr)

Please note that nbconvert includes other widgets fine and also tabs with other content.

This is the used code:

```py
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np

# Generated data for plotting
data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(5):
    data[i] = np.random.normal(size = 50)
```

Now this part works in the notebook but not in the html, but as you will see it seems to be related to the output widget, as I does not work with plots or printed text.

```py
# This does not work with plots
children = []
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    out = widgets.Output()
    with out:
        fig, axes = plt.subplots()
        data[i].hist(ax = axes)
        plt.show()
    children.append(out)
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.children = children
for i in range(len(children)):
    tab.set_title(i, "Plot " + str(i))
tab

# And this does not work with printed output
children = []
for i in range(5):
    out = widgets.Output()
    with out:
        print("This is text", i)
    children.append(out)
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.children = children
for i in range(len(children)):
    tab.set_title(i, "Text " + str(i))
tab
```

However, if I use a different widget type (e.g. Text) it is displayed correctly in the notebook and the html output from nbconvert.

```py
# This works with the Text widget
children = []
for i in range(5):
    out = widgets.Text(description="P"+str(i))
    children.append(out)
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.children = children
for i in range(len(children)):
    tab.set_title(i, "Text " + str(i))
tab
```

So, is there something I can change to make this actually work? What I need in the end is a way to display N plots in N tabs...

Comment: Using an observe method solved it for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949504/how-to-lazify-output-in-tabbed-layout-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried using nbconvert with `--ExecutePreprocessor.store_widget_state=True` it does store the state but the output goes to the wrong cell. The only solution right now is to open Jupyter Notebook, and run it manually then go Widgets > Save Widget State. Then use nbconvert, that would show the output where it should be. I think the problem is that nbconvert doesnt have a JS engine (for obvious reasons) so its not possible to do what we want.

Comment: I reported an issue upstream [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Updating `nbconvert` (for example via `pip install --upgrade nbconvert`) solved it.

Quoting from https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/923 :

> MSeal commented on 2020-09-07:
>
> Yes, this issue was resolved in [jupyter/nbclient#24](https://github.com/jupyter/nbclient/issues/24) and nbclient >=
> 0.4.0 has the fix. NBconvert 6.0 (which should be releasing tomorrow) defaults to using nbclient and the issue overall should disappear. You
> can try it out on the 6.0.0rc0 release today if you like.